# What is the correct way to NULLIFY i.e. remove a key in FaceBook API

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api

I have an event  with the "end_time" facebook key set.  I know want to remove the end time for the event.  What is the correct syntax ? Samples i've tried shown;

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"none", @"end_time", nil];
FBRequest *deleteEndDate = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"/<EVENT_ID>" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"", @"end_time", nil];
FBRequest *deleteEndDate = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"/<EVENT_ID>" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];


FBRequest *deleteEndDate = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"/<EVENT_ID>/end_time" parameters:Nil HTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"", @"end_time", nil];
FBRequest *deleteEndDate = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"/<EVENT_ID>" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"DELETE"]; // Deletes the event !!
```

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting it to @"0" removes it from the facebook event display in facebook app

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in [NSNull null] or making the request with "/EVENT_ID" and passing nil for parameters.

Comment: Can't send [NSNull null] as the method requestWithGraphPath issues a call to the length method on the NSString passed, and [NSNull null] is of type NSNull resulting in an exception.

Comment: Just to be clear, you tried `NSDictionary *params = @{@"end_time":[NSNull null]};` right? I have never had an error calling count on an NSDictionary with a [NSNull value].

Comment: I had it the other way around which crashes your way does not crash it gives bad URL as FaceBook seems to expect the key as the second item in the dictionary list.

Comment: Got an answer by trial and error setting the field to @"0" nullifies it for facebook